# If statement wont stop running until its definition is met

Tags: python

I am working on a basic facial recognition program and I am trying to implement a timeout system to lock the computer. Basically it should wait one second then add 1 to the counter if the counter reaches 10 then it activates an if statement to lock the computer. But when running this it wont run any other part of the code until it sees a face. I am fairly new to this so any help is appreciated.

```
        def facecheck():

            if matches == face_recognition.compare_faces(taylor_face_encoding, known_face_encodings):
                print("Confirmed")
                Confirm = True
                exit()
            else:
                print("Negative")
                correct-=1
                if correct <= -3:
                    print("User disallowed!")
                    subprocess.call('/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend',shell=True)
                    exit()
        while continue1 == 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Counting")
            countdown+=1
            facecheck()
```

Comment: your `while` statement compares `continue1` variable, while you are changing `countdown` variable. This loop will never stop.

Comment: By the way, there's little point in setting the value of `Confirm` if you are immediately calling `exit`

Comment: Yes I am aware It will be used for another part of code later down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not seem to resemble exactly the process you are describing, but your problem at hand is, that your code is running in a single process, and therefore, while being in the loop, nothing else executes. For this there is the `multiprocessing as well as the threading` package. With that you start a decoupled process that runs next to it.
Minimal example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def facecheck():
  timer = 0
  while True:
    if timer > 10:
       if face_accepted:
         timer = 0
       else:
         lock()
    timer +=1
    sleep(1)
  [...]

proc = Process(target=facecheck, args=(client, addr))
proc.start()
```

The above would start a process, that waits for 10 seconds, then does a face check (implementation of `face_accepted` required) and if face is accepted waits another 10 seconds to recheck. If the face is not accepted, the system is locked (`lock()` required) and face is checked every second until correct face is presented